# Zimbra Java Client - Getting Started?

Tags: java, zimbra

Is there any documentation about the Zimbra Java Client library (how to use it?, API Javadoc, etc) and where can I find it?

I'm talking about the famous com.zimbra.cs.zclient.ZMailbox class.

Thanks.

Comment: where do you get it?  jar finder comes back blank..

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can download the source code on https://github.com/Zimbra-Community/zimbra-sources, and read the javadocs on the source code.